# How can I sort a list based on a float inside each string in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to sort a list based on a certain part of each string. How do I write the key?

```py
myKey(e)
  return e[-5,-2]

print(sorted(["A: (" + str(round(7.24856, 2)) + ")", "B: (" + str(round(5.8333, 2)) + ")"], key = myKey))
```

I want the output to look like this: `['B: (5.83)', 'A: (7.25)']`

In my full code, there are more than two strings in the list, so I cannot just sort them reversed alphabetically.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried and call you please show all of the releveant code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing exactly? Are you starting with numbers, and want to use them to produce sorted strings? Or are you starting with the numbers already in string form, and you need to sort them numerically anyway? Are there any limits on the numeric values (for instance, are they all less than 10)? It's not easy to tell from your example how complicated the parsing task might be.

Comment: please specify your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for function `myKey` is wrong. Other than that, you have to slice out the number in the string with the correct index (from index of char '(' + 1 to the character before the last) and convert them to floating point number value so that the `sorted` function can work properly.

```
def myKey(e):
  return float(e[e.index('(')+1:-1])
print(sorted(["A: (" + str(round(7.24856, 2)) + ")", "B: (" + str(round(5.8333, 2)) + ")"], key = myKey))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuples `sorted()` to sort your data alongside with some list and string expressions to get the desired output:

```
input_list = ['A:(100.27)', 'B:(2.36)', 'C:(75.96)', 'D:(55.78)']
tuples_list = [(e.split(':(')[0], float(e.split(':(')[1][:-1])) for e in input_list]
sorted_tuples = sorted(tuples_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
result = [x[0] +':('+ str(x[1]) +')' for x in sorted_tuples]

print(input_list)
print(tuples_list)
print(sorted_tuples)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['A:(100.27)', 'B:(2.36)', 'C:(75.96)', 'D:(55.78)']
[('A', 100.27), ('B', 2.36), ('C', 75.96), ('D', 55.78)]
[('B', 2.36), ('D', 55.78), ('C', 75.96), ('A', 100.27)]
['B:(2.36)', 'D:(55.78)', 'C:(75.96)', 'A:(100.27)']
```